# Axes-Reordering event on parallel coordinates

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, listener, parallel-coordinates

i m still working on a parallel coordinates plot using https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates#parallel-coordinates and d3.js

i need to update something after the axes are reordered.
So try to add an listener to the parcoords, but i don't find how the event is called which is fired when the axes are reordered.

I use the .reorderable() method to enable the reordering.
I tried

```
 parcoords.on("dimensions",function (){
                alert('reorder');
            });
```

but "dimensions" is not the right event, it is only triggered after changing the axes using the .dimensions() method.
I went through the examples of the library, but only found on brush events, and went through the api description, but didn't found the right event.

the question is: what is the reorder event called?

thanks in advance
greetings Jones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the event is called "axesreorder".

it and other events can be found here: https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates/blob/master/src/events.js (first line)